PANDAS set one column to index and another column to fields
I have the following Dataframe in PANDAS:
Index         Job Title                      Year               Salary

0     POL - POL 47 HQ Police Chief           2022               243000

1     POL - POL 47 HQ Police Chief           2023               258000

2     CAT - CAT 30 County Attorney           2022               220000

3     CAT - CAT 30 County Attorney           2022               236000

4     CAT - CAT 30 County Attorney           2023               258000

5     DOT - DOT 50 Director                  2022               228000

6     DOT - DOT 50 Director                  2023               244000

7     POL - HQ Police Chief                  2019               239566

8     POL - HQ Police Chief                  2020               225000

9     POL - HQ Police Chief                  2021               236000

10    IGR - IGR 20 Director                  2022               232000

11    IGR - IGR 20 Director                  2023               232000

12    FIN - FIN 32 Director                  2022               220000

13    FIN - FIN 32 Director                  2023               236000

14    PRO - PRO 35 Procurement Director      2022               220000

I'm trying to find a way to set unique 'Year' column values to the index and set unique 'Job Title' values as fields. The values in the 'Salary' column would then populate the cells where 'Year' and 'Job Title' intersect. If there is no value corresponding to the intersection it should return 0 or NaN.
It should look like this:
          POL - HQ Police Chief         FIN - FIN 32 Director       PRO - PRO 35 Procurement Director

2019           239566                           NaN                              NaN

2020           225000                           Nan                              NaN

2021           236000                           NaN                              NaN

2022           NaN                              220000                           220000

2023           NaN                              236000                           NaN

Thanks for the help!
I've been messing around with setting the index and transposing, but I've only succeeded in making non-functional dataframes with lots of duplicates or redundancies.

Try pd.crosstab like this:
pd.crosstab(df['Year'], df['Job Title'], df['Salary'], aggfunc='sum')

Output:
Job Title  CAT - CAT 30 County Attorney  DOT - DOT 50 Director  FIN - FIN 32 Director  IGR - IGR 20 Director  POL - HQ Police Chief  POL - POL 47 HQ Police Chief  PRO - PRO 35 Procurement Director
Year                                                                                                                                                                                                
2019                                NaN                    NaN                    NaN                    NaN               239566.0                           NaN                                NaN
2020                                NaN                    NaN                    NaN                    NaN               225000.0                           NaN                                NaN
2021                                NaN                    NaN                    NaN                    NaN               236000.0                           NaN                                NaN
2022                           456000.0               228000.0               220000.0               232000.0                    NaN                      243000.0                           220000.0
2023                           258000.0               244000.0               236000.0               232000.0                    NaN                      258000.0                                NaN

